# How to design and use CNNs for sentence classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, text-classification

I'm playing around with using CNNs for sentence classification. Basically all models I found implement the same model proposed in [Convolutional Neural Networks for Sentence Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5882) (Kim, 2014), where multiple convolutional layers are used in "parallel" for different window sizes (reflecting different n-gram sizes):
[image]

I even [implemented the model](https://github.com/chrisvdweth/ml-toolkit/blob/master/pytorch/models/text/classifier/cnn.py), and it works fine. However, now I have 2 main questions now:

1. Is there something "intuitive" these filters are learning? For example, in the case of image classification, these first/early filters typically learns basic edges in different directions. Can we say anything similar in case of sentence classification.
2. Why haven't I seen CNN models for sentence classification with multiple sequential convolutional layers? Is there some intrinsic reason why this is not a good idea in case of text data?